# get emoji iOS on Android

Tags: android, android-appcompat, emoji

Is there any way to get emoji iOS on TextView in Android using the **com.android.support:support-emoji:28.0.0**

I would like to avoid opensource library for that one.. please any help ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use unicode for emoji.

Here is the link: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

To use it in Android, you need to replace **U+** with **0x** so it will be an integer.

To set unicode  as a text in your `TextView` you can use;

Java:

```
public String createEmoji(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun createEmoji(unicode: Int): String {
    return    String(Character.toChars(unicode)) 
}
```